# Check if textfield is empty before to insert into CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift4

I have 4 UITextFields and a UIButton (Save Button). 
When I press the Save button it should add what I have in my textfields into CoreData and also to populate the data in a UITableView.
But the problem is when I don't put anything in my TextFields and I press Save is adding me an empty object into my CoreData and also into my UITableView.

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var productNameTextfield: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var productCategoryTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var productDescriptionTextfield: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var productPriceTextfield: UITextField!

       // Func to insert data from TextFields into DB
        func insertProduct(){

            let product = Product(context: context)
            let productUUID = UUID().uuidString
            product.id = productUUID

            if (productNameTextfield.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty)! {
                showAlertWith(title: "Name required", message: "Product name is required !")
            }
            else if (productCategoryTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty)! {
                showAlertWith(title: "Category required", message: "Product Category required !")
            }
            else if (productDescriptionTextfield.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty)! {
                showAlertWith(title: "Description required", message: "Product Description required !")
            }
            else if (productPriceTextfield.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty)! {
                showAlertWith(title: "Price required", message: "Product Price required !")
            }
            else{
                guard let productPrice = (productPriceTextfield.text ?? "").isEmpty ? "0.00" : productPriceTextfield.text else { return }
                product.name = self.productNameTextfield.text!
                product.category = self.productCategoryTextField.text!
                product.prodDescription = self.productDescriptionTextfield.text!
                product.price = Float(productPrice)!
                appDelegate.saveContext()
                resetAllFields()
                showAlertWith(title: "Done", message: "Product was added with success !")
            }
        }
```

Here is my CoreData:

[image]

And here is my bug on the interface:

[image]

Any idea will help me a lot !
Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CoreData object gets created and inserted into the context as soon as you call the line `Product(context: context)`. Move those lines to the beginning of your `else` block:

```
    ...
} else {
    let product = Product(context: context)
    let productUUID = UUID().uuidString
    product.id = productUUID

    guard let productPrice = (productPriceTextfield.text ?? "").isEmpty ? "0.00" : productPriceTextfield.text else { return }
    ...
```